# sed delete also part of IP address

Tags: sed

can please somebody help me with this?
I have this line

test.txt

`siemplog1.nw.lan / 172.31.180.22`

I tried this command `sed -Ei "s/^[a-z A-Z].*([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/" test.txt`

result should be `172.31.180.22` but I got this `2.31.180.22`

thank you

Comment: can you add more sample input lines and describe the problem better? for the given sample, `awk '{print $NF}' test.txt` would work too

Comment: Glad [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61055718/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.*` matches as many chars as it can (it is "greedy") and since `[0-9]{1,3}` can match just 1 digit, the `17` is matched by the `.*` and `2` is matched by `[0-9]{1,3}`.

You may stop the `.*` before any non-digit:

```
sed -Ei 's~.*[^0-9]([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*~\1~' test.txt
```

Or, before `/`:

```
sed -Ei 's~.*/ *([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*~\1~' test.txt
```

See [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/16wUyM):

```
s='siemplog1.nw.lan / 172.31.180.22'
sed -E 's~.*/ *([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*~\1~' <<< "$s"
# => 172.31.180.22
```

If you string is always in this format, you might simplify the sed command to

```
sed -E 's~.*/ *([0-9.]+)~\1~p'
sed -E 's~.*/ *([0-9.]+).*~\1~p'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have space before ip

```
$echo siemplog1.nw.lan / 172.31.180.22 | sed -E "s/.* ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/"
172.31.180.22
$
```